Is there a name for a pair of morphisms such that $f \circ g \circ f = f$?
I was thinking about useful weaker notions of inverses and came upon this one, so I wonder is there a name for a pair of morphisms $f$, $g$ in a category such that $f \circ g \circ f = f$?
I've been looking around and haven't found anything. The closest thing I found was generalized inverses, but that is about matrices and not morphisms in general.
The condition implies that both of their compositions $f \circ g$ and $g \circ f$ are idempotent.
I guess it's also a special case of $h \circ g \circ f = h$ where $h$ is viewed as a lens under which to consider their equality. Does this other construction have a name?

The context is a pair of transformations of code between two languages such that their composition is idempotent, but they aren't necessarily inverses (e.g. could make idempotent formatting changes as well). This condition is very weak, since transforming the whole file into an empty file would be valid as well. The other variation with $h$ could be used for e.g. checking that if the code is formatted or compiled, it gives the same result.

I am not sure what prevents you from taking the name "generalized inverse" when it precisely restricts to the usual meaning for the category of finite-dimensional vector spaces?

Mostly because I was hoping that someone else had already written something about it and I couldn't find anything. And because the notions I found had additional conditions that doesn't trivially generalize

The closest things I know are retractions and sections (corresponding to morphisms which have right inverses and left inverses, respectively).

Wikipedia says "Generalized inverses can be defined in any mathematical structure that involves associative multiplication, that is, in a semigroup", so it's not only for matrices. See also Weak inverse. I don't know the name in the precise context of category theory
